# Datalogics initialization and AdobeFnt13.1.lst

Tags: adobe-pdf-library

For initialization of the Datalogics APDFL 10.1.0 I'm calling the following code:

```
pdflData.pluginDirListLen = PDFLGetDirList2(&pdflData.pluginDirList, sBinPath, _T(""));
```

I have noticed that this will generate a file `AdobeFnt13.1.lst` listing all files in the specified directory including all subfolders recursively.
Excerpts:

```
%BeginFont
Handler:DirectoryHandler
FontType:Invalid
OutlineFileName:C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProgram\MyModule.pdb
FileModTime:1520519039
%EndFont

%BeginFont
Handler:DirectoryHandler
FontType:Invalid
OutlineFileName:C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProgram\MyProgram.chm
FileModTime:1370341752
%EndFont
```

This seems to be wrong, as I want to announce any "plug-in" to the library, only.
The ***.ppi** files in particular. For example the "DL100PDFProcessor.ppi".

Is there any harm in having such listing auto-generated?
I couldn't find much information on those **AdobeFnt*.lst** files so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at our [sample code](https://github.com/datalogics/adobe-pdf-library-samples/blob/master/CPlusPlus/Sample_Source/_Common/InitializeLibrary.cpp#L216) for library initialization you will see you just need to point *pluginDirList* to point to the path where your PDFL binaries live.  Note: The sample code is for v15 of PDFL, but the concepts are applicable in v10.

You don't have to worry about interacting with *AdobeFnt*.lst* file normally as PDFL manages it automatically and it deals with lookup of directories to find resources on the machine.

If you can't quickly get started based on my answer, please contact Support and they would be happy to assist you.